# Moving paper documents to cloud (AWS) -

Tags: python, aws, cloud-computing

I'm trying to solve a simple problem and seeking advise/suggestions - I have lot of paper documents in my drawers which I want to store on cloud (S3) as PDFs.

My idea blueprint is -

1) scanning all of them using printer

2) store it locally in organised folder structure

3) upload them to S3 cloud - (python code using Boto3 ?)

Questions -

1) Does this sound good to start with? Please advise.

2) Is S3 the best for this in AWS stack? Or, anything else? (Apologies, completely new to AWS stack, hence aware of all its services and offerings.)

Fyi, I'm currently working on AWS Free Tier.

Thanks in advance!
Ranit

ps. This's my first post/question on AWS and my SO account is blocked to ask questions. Sincere apologies if it lacks essential details.